# Sending an email with C# with a hostinger domain and email account

Tags: c#, email

Hi I am trying to send an email using C# code, I tried different libraries but I am getting the same error with all of them which means its something external but cannot figure out what it is.

It fails when sending the email, the rest of the code is configuration.

The error is "Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

namespace EmailSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string smtpServer = "smtp.hostinger.com"; 
                int smtpPort = 465; 
                string smtpUsername = "I put here the email account that I created under the domain I created"; 
                string smtpPassword = "I put here the password I generated for the email under the domain I created"; 

                string fromEmail = "same as the smtpUsername";
                string toEmail = "Any random existing email";
                string subject = "Test Email";
                string body = "This is a test email sent using C# and MailKit.";

                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("", fromEmail));
                message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", toEmail));
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };

                using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(smtpServer, smtpPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    client.Authenticate(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                    client.Send(message);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                if (ex is SmtpCommandException smtpEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"SMTP Response: {smtpEx.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails with... what? What's the error?

Comment: Post updated with the error.

Comment: I have retracted my down vote and close vote. Please make sure you include the relevant details like error messages in your post in the future, don't wait for someone to remind you.

Comment: Did you try port 587, as recommended by Hostinger? https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1575756-how-to-get-email-account-configuration-details-for-hostinger-email

Comment: You could leave the downvote it is a good way to learn I wanted to show the error at the beginning but I was doing multiple things at the same time which ended in multiple thing done wrong sorry for that. mason's answer is correct, under my settings in hostinger it said port 465 for SMTP but you are right it is port 587.